# How can I determine the set S is vectorspace or not ? I have to prove it

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following set
:[image]

How to determine whether the subset V is subspace or not?
To prove that a given subset S is a subspace, I need to hold the conditions universally, so in that case I should use variables and check that linear combinations of elements of V still satisfy the defining property of V. This is all I know but I'm struggling with this set.

Comment: If $3x-2y+z=0$ and $3x'-2y'+z'=0$, does $3(x+x')-2(y+y')+(z+z')=0$?  does $3(cx)-2(cy)+cz=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. $V$ is non-empty.

Note that $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\end{bmatrix} \in V$ and thus, $V \neq \varnothing$.

> 2. $V$ is closed under addition.

That is, if $u$ and $v$ are elements of $V$, then so is $u+v$.
Note that if $u, v \in V$, then $u = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\end{bmatrix}$ for some scalars $x, y, z$ satisfying $3x - 2y + z = 0$. Similarly, we have $v = \begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\\\end{bmatrix}$ for some scalars $x', y', z'$ satisfying $3x' - 2y' + z' = 0$.

Now, we compute $u+v$ and show that it must belong to $V$. Note that $u+v = \begin{bmatrix}x+x'\\y+y'\\z+z'\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\\\end{bmatrix}$.

To show that $u+v \in V$, we need to show that $3X - 2Y + Z = 0$. This follows easily because $3X - 2Y + Z = 3(x + x') - 2(y + y') + z + z' = (3x - 2y + z) + (3x' - 2y' + z') = 0 + 0 = 0$.

Thus, we are done.

> 3. $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

That is, if $v \in V$ and $c$ is a scalar, then $cv \in V$.

Using the method as earlier, it is easy to show that this is indeed the case by observing that $3cx - 2cy + cz = c(3x - 2y + z)$.

---

By the above three observations, we have shown that $V$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

$V= \ker \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and the null space is a vector space.